# How to inherit of a scene tree structure in a way that a change in the ancestor is updated in the descendant?

Tags: godot, inheritance, gdscript

Consider this structure:

```
* KinematicBody2D (Actor)
|_ AnimationPlayer (able to make a rotation of 360)
```

Now I want to make a Player and an Enemy that inherits of that structure in a way that when I change the animation on the Actor Scene, Enemy and Player are updated.

Is there a pattern that allows that?

Comment: Would this help: https://github.com/smix8/GodotAnimationRetargeting (see the branches)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an inherited scene. From the "Scene" menu, select "New Inherited Scene…" and pick the base scene. Then apply the modifications you need (e.g. change textures).

---

There is also a composition equivalent:

- Create a new scene.
- Add the "base" scene as a node.
- Make it editable ("Editable Children" on the context menu on the Scene panel).
- Then add the modifications you need (e.g. change textures).

---

Either way, you cannot remove from the original, only add or modify. And whatever you didn't change will be inherited from the base scene.

Comment: If a script is associated with the ancestor, will it be inherited also?

Comment: @pietrodito It gets the same scripts, not inherited scripts if that is what you mean. And no, you cannot put two scripts on a node. For new behavior I suggest to add a node with a new script. Addendum: you can use signals as extension points. Where there is some behavior that the derived scene should provide, emit the signal, and then in the derived scene connect the signal to the new node that has the new script for that.

Comment: I think I understand the composition pattern now...